# Swapping largest and smallest numbers in C

Tags: c

I want to write a program that reads 10 `int` values from the user and swaps the largest and smallest numbers on the first and second values, then the rest of the numbers should be in the order.

Please check the code and help me what the wrong is.

For instance:

```
1
9
4
5
6
7
8
2
4
5
```

New order should be `9 1 4 5 6 7 8 2 4 5`

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {

    int a[10],i,min,max=0,pos=0;

    printf("Please enter 10 int values :\n");
    do{
    scanf("%d", &a[pos++]);
    } while (pos<10);

    for (i=0; i<10;i++) {
    printf("%i\n",a[i]);

    if (max<a[i])
    {
max=a[i];
}

    if (min>a[i])

    {
min=a[i];
    }

    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {

    if (a[i]==max) 
a[i]=max;

    if (a[i] == min) a[i] = min;

    }  

    printf("The new order is : %d %d %d ", max, min, ...);

    return 0;   
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
It is the new form

    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {

        int a[10],i,pos,temp,min = 0,max = 0;

        printf("Please enter 10 int values :\n");

        do {

        scanf("%d", &a[pos++]);

        } while (pos < 10);

        for ( =1; i<10;i++) {

        if (a[i]>a[max]) 
{
max=i;
}

        if (a[i]<a[min]) 
{
min=i;
}
        }

        temp=a[max];

        a[max]=a[min];

        a[min]=temp;

        printf("%d %d",a[max],a[min]);

        for (i=0;i<10;i++){

        if ((i != min) && (i != max)) {

        printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }

        }

        printf("\n");

        return 0;   
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: @Erkan  What is " the first and second order"?!

Comment: Thank you for the advices. Actually program is simple,that's why i needed to explain like this.@TobySpeight

It is like blank. I mean it will show 10 value,the first value should be the largest and second value is smallest number. @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @Erkan Thus you will need to move elements of the array to the right side?

Comment: Yes. After two values which are max and min,the values should be the same as the user write on the keyboard. @VladfromMoscow

Comment: `if(a[i]==max) a[i]=max;`  Do you think this line actually accomplishes anything at all??

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your code does not properly identify the maximum and minimum values in the array because you are writing `min` and `max` back into the array instead of the other way around.

Since you want to swap these values, what you actually want are the *indices* of  the min and max values of the array, and swap those.

It is best to break this code into functions instead of having everything in main.  Here is a solution that will do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int indexofmax(int *data, int len)
{
    int max = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(data[i]>data[max]) max = i;
    }
    return max;
}


int indexofmin(int *data, int len)
{
    int min = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(data[i]<data[min]) min = i;
    }
    return min;
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main()
{
   // user enters in 10 ints...
   int max = indexofmax(a, 10);
   int min = indexofmin(a, 10);
   int i;
   swap(&a[min], &a[max]);
   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       printf("%d ", a[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiler shows a mistake for that

int max = indexofmax(a, 10);

[Error] 'a' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: @Erkan are you just copying my whole code? What I gave you was a snippet of main that you should integrate with your current code.

Comment: It is complicated for me to understand this code,as you see on my code i am an inexperienced person @Govind

Comment: @Erkan StackOverflow is not a free code writing service

Comment: I know. Can u see any expectation from my question to re-write the code by someone? I just told you that it is complicated for me :) @Govind

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually altering the array.

In the second loop, you say "if the current element is the max, set it to the max".  In other words, set it to its current value.  Similarly for the min.

What you want is to swap those assignments.

```
if(a[i]==max) a[i]=min;

if(a[i]==min) a[i]=max;
```

Also, your initial values for `min` and `max` are no good.  `min` is unitialized, so its initial value is undefined.  You should initialize `min` to a very large value, and similarly `max` should be initialized to a very small (i.e. large negative) value.

A better way to do this would be to keep track of the **index** of the largest and smallest values.  These you can initialize to 0.  Then you can check `a[i] > a[max]` and `a[i] < a[min]`.  Then you print the values at indexes `min` and `max`, then loop through the list and print the others.

```
int i, temp, min=0, max=0;

for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
    if (a[i] > a[max]) max = i;
    if (a[i] < a[min]) min = i;
}

printf("%d %d ", a[max], a[min]);
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if ((i != min) && (i != max)) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: You are right. I thought that if i assign max. and min. values,then i can swap them on the first and second order.

How can i assign them and remark on the new order?

Comment: Well,you used temp to write on the screen,right? So,how can i write on the screen? I mean user will write 10 int value, just the first which is the largest and second value,which is the smallest, should swap. Rest of the numbers will be the same.

Comment: @Erkan See my edit.  Omit the swap, and use the code at the bottom to print.

Comment: I edited some parts but still there is a problem on somewhere. Can you check please? @dbush

Comment: @Erkan You didn't omit the swapping of the min and max like I said.  Get rid of those lines.

Comment: Is it okay now? @dbush

Comment: There is a problem with swapping now. Check please @dbush

Comment: @Erkan What problem, specifically?

Comment: 1)User enters 10 value
2)The largest and smallest number will swap instead of first and second value
3)Re-write underline and rest of 8 numbers will write beside them.

Third part is the problem. @dbush

Comment: @Erkan At this point, you should post a new question with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

This initialization `min=0,max=0` is not right.

Instead have `min = INT_MAX` and `max = INT_MIN`.

By setting `min=0`, you would never get the lowest number in the array if it is greater than 0.

Similarly by setting `max=0`, you would never get the greatest number in the array if it is lower than 0.

You are gaining **nothing** by this code:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)

{ if(a[i]==max) a[i]=max;

  if(a[i]==min) a[i]=min; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is evident that this loop

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)

{ if(a[i]==max) a[i]=max;

if(a[i]==min) a[i]=min; }
```

does not make sense.

Moreover variable `min` is not initialized while variable `max` is initialized incorrectly.

```
int a[10],i,min,max=0,pos=0;
```

For example the array can contain all negative elements. In this case you will get incorrect value of the maximum equal to 0.

And I do not see where the elements are moved to the right to place the maximum and the minimum to the first two positions of the array.

If I have understood correctly then what you need is something like the following. To move the elements you could use standard function `memmove` declared in header `<string.h>`. However it seems you are learning loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int main( void )
{
    int a[N] = { 4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 1, 8, 2, 4, 5 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    size_t min = 0;
    size_t max = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (a[max] < a[i])
        {
            max = i;
        }
        else if (a[i] < a[min])
        {
            min = i;
        }
    }

    if (max != min)
    {
        int min_value = a[min];
        int max_value = a[max];

        size_t j = N;
        for (size_t i = N; i != 0; --i)
        {
            if (i - 1 != min && i - 1 != max)
            {
                if (i != j)
                {
                    a[j - 1] = a[i - 1];
                }
                --j;
            }
        }

        a[--j] = min_value;
        a[--j] = max_value;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

The program output is

```
4 5 9 6 7 1 8 2 4 5
9 1 4 5 6 7 8 2 4 5
```

Comment: Yes. I am new for programming. Your code looks perfect but i can not understand part of them. What is ' size_t ' ? @vladfrommoscow

Comment: @Erkan It is an unsigned integer type. You can substitute it everywhere in the program for the type int or unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it nice and simple, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXNUM 10

int find_biggest(int A[], size_t n);
int find_smallest(int A[], size_t n);
void print_array(int A[], size_t n);
void int_swap(int *a, int *b);

int
main(void) {
    int array[MAXNUM], i, smallest, biggest;

    printf("Please enter 10 int values:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < MAXNUM; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("Before: ");
    print_array(array, MAXNUM);

    smallest = find_smallest(array, MAXNUM);
    biggest = find_biggest(array, MAXNUM);

    int_swap(&array[smallest], &array[biggest]);

    printf("After: ");
    print_array(array, MAXNUM);

    return 0;
}

int
find_biggest(int A[], size_t n) {
    int biggest, i, idx_loc;

    biggest = A[0];
    idx_loc = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (A[i] > biggest) {
            biggest = A[i];
            idx_loc = i;
        }
    }

    return idx_loc;
}

int
find_smallest(int A[], size_t n) {
    int smallest, i, idx_loc;

    smallest = A[0];
    idx_loc = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (A[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = A[i];
            idx_loc = i;
        }
    }

    return idx_loc;
}

void
print_array(int A[], size_t n) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void
int_swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```